# How can i filter data from google adsense api using page url?

Tags: php, laravel, api, adsense, adsense-api

i need to send custom filter to google adsense api v2

something like this

```
$optParams = array(
  'filters' => array(
    "URL_CHANNEL_NAME=@https://example.com/test/*"
    //or "URL_CHANNEL_NAME==https://example.com/test/"
  )
);
```

to get only earnings for this url "https://example.com/test" or "https://example.com/test/*"

i have tried "URL_CHANNEL_NAME==https://example.com/test/" or even "URL_CHANNEL_NAME==https://example.com/test/" but reponse always null
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7yk1V.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to target all channels that begin with a certain URL

```php
$optParams = [
    'filters' => [
        'URL_CHANNEL_NAME=@^https://example\.com/test'
     ]
);
```

There is also "contains" but "contains" with URLs can in edge-case scenarios return undesirable results:

```
URL_CHANNEL_NAME@https://example.com/test
```

It also could just have no data for the date range you're using, you won't receive anything if that is the case.

Comment: i have cheked date range and when i remove filters it works ,
--

Comment: Then there is no data for the channels you’re after in the date range you’ve specified

Comment: no, there is .. and when i remove this "'filters' => []" it appears

Comment: Azure are really vague on this type of stuff unfortunately, did you attempt the regex?